Can a 12-inch depth floor tom be retrofitted as a snare drum?
I recently acquired a new drum kit that includes two floor toms, one of which has a 14" diameter and 12" depth. I would like to modify 14 x 12 drum to make it a hybrid floor tom/deep snare, as demonstrated by Larnell Lewis and Sput in this video: 

 However, there they use an 14 x 8 drum instead.
How feasible would a 12" depth snare be, particularly regarding tuning range and responsiveness? Are there significant constraints regarding what heads (single/double ply) would work? I would like to know if this is a non-starter idea before I drill holes and buy a new snare strainer for this modification.
I have extensive experience tuning cheap kits with branded heads very carefully to make them sound good. However, I have almost no idea about how to navigate variables like drum depth. My existing snare is a 6" deep steel snare tuned very high, but I'd like a low deep option too, hence my interest in a hybrid tom/snare.
I don't really mind if this ends up sacrificing the drum's usability as a tom: hybrid would be nice, but it's more important that this function as a deep snare than as a tom.

Roughly speaking, diameter affects pitch and depth affects sustain and volume. The floor tom legs you’d have to use might get in the way of the kick or high hat pedals. Otherwise, you’re basically building a marching snare. You can tune a 14x6.5 snare pretty low.

No real reason at all. It is most likely made of wood, so will resonate differently from your metal snare, and probably you'll keep the two in your kit. After all, it'll still be available to play in its original role as a smaller (if you like) floor tom.
That's said, as your original snare will be between your legs, putting the deep snare away from the kick drum and hi-hat mechanisms. That means you'll still be able to keep the tripod arrangement - a snare drum stand won't be too stable anyway.
Being wood, it'll be easier to make the appropriate holes for the strainer, etc.
It won't have the 'ping' of the steel snare, but sound more like the hybrid it is, but that's what you want, isn't it? The heads can stay the same - the batter worked as a tom, so why wouldn't it work as a snare batter?
Sounds like an interesting project. Please let us know later how it pans out with the rest of your kit!

Have you done this, or do you know someone who has?

@ojs - no, this is the 'theory' part of the site!

As a person with with some science background I believe there's a difference between theory and just making up stuff.

@ojs - not wishing to get into a slanging match. I watched the video, applied logic, and came to the conclusion that if the concept worked (and it did) on a smaller tom, there would be no reason for it not to work on a deeper one. If I had a spare tom, it's the sort of thing I might well do as a bit of a project. End of the day, the tom would still be perfectly serviceable for its original purpose.

“The heads can stay the same” you can probably keep the batter head, but the resonator head almost certainly will have to be a snare resonator. He says this in the video.

@ToddWilcox - having done some more homework, yes, an ordinary resonator head as found under a tom will sound a lot darker/deeper, but it seems some drummers prefer this. As usual, I'm learning a lot from this site. Except that from an engineering background, 3mil was never 0.003" I still call that 'three thou'. Interesting how drums/cymbals have retained their imperial measurements...

Love to know why the dv was awarded.
